# Saved Games Snapshot metadata outdated on first call

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Here's the scenario:

1. User plays on **Device 1**, reaches level 2. At this point, the app commits the snapshot with the description "Level 2".
2. User launches app on **Device 2**. The app syncs the data and restores the progress using `open`. Snapshot metadata description is correct ("Level 2").
3. User plays on **Device 1** again, this time reaching level 3. The app then commits the snapshot with the description "Level 3".
4. User launches app on **Device 2** again. The app syncs the data and restores the progress again using `open`. However, the metadata in the snapshot is still "Level 2" but the actual data is correct - progress is at level 3. The metadata only gets updated when I call open() again.

Any ideas why this happens? Right now my workaround is to just call `open()` twice in succession which is really bad.

***Edit***

To make it clearer, here's a shorter flow:

1. Commit snapshot with description -- let's call this **Snapshot A**
2. Commit snapshot with description -- let's call this **Snapshot B**
3. Call open() -> returns **Snapshot B** data (correct) but with **Snapshot A** description (incorrect)
4. Call open() again -> returns **Snapshot B** data (correct) with **Snapshot B** description (correct)

Nothing else is done in between the steps above.

So the issue I'm getting is that I always need to call open twice to get the correct data AND description.

Comment: Charmel, quite unclear question. Can you please ellaborate your problem in brief?

Comment: Well to make it really short, when I use open() to get the latest snapshot, the metadata is outdated -- meaning, the metadata returned with the snapshot is for two commits ago. I need to call open() again for the metadata to get updated.

Comment: @pratt Edited the question details. I hope it's clearer now. :)

Comment: Charmel, can you post your code, so I can read properly.

Comment: Are you setting `forceUpdate` to true when loading Snapshots? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots.html#load(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, boolean)